# returning the entire sentence and not just line

Tags: sed, awk, grep

grep shows the lines where the search word is found. I have a text file where there is no line break and entire text is on a single line. Is there any way to instruct grep to show the contents of the left and right (just like -after, -before)?

I will like to see the entire sentence. The words between 2 fullstops. (i.e. the sentence where the word is found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily chop the text into lines:

```
cat text.txt | sed 's/\./.\n/g' | grep pattern
```

Answer (score 2):

Use awk with the period as record separator and filter the records on the required pattern:

```
awk -v RS="." '/pattern/' file
```

Which is shorthand for:

```
awk -v RS="." '/pattern/{print}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -o '[^.]*word[^.]*\.' file
```